# Symfony 5 : Add Collection in twig template

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have a `Subscribers` entity and a `PaInstance` entity (PA) . These two are related as one `subscriber` can have many `PaInstances` and the relation works. My problem is that in the twig template for `show_subscriber` , I want to use the  `addPaInstance` function and i just don`t know how to do that .
This is the Subscribers entity :

```
class Subscribers
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
  /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=PaInstances::class, mappedBy="subscriber")
     */
    private $paInstances;
   public function __construct()
    {$this->paInstances = new ArrayCollection(); }
    
 /**
     * @return Collection|PaInstances[]
     */
    public function getPaInstances(): Collection
    {
        return $this->paInstances;
    }

    public function addPaInstance(PaInstances $paInstance): self
    {
        if (!$this->paInstances->contains($paInstance)) {
            $this->paInstances[] = $paInstance;
            $paInstance->setSubscriber($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
   public function removePaInstance(PaInstances $paInstance): self
    {
        if ($this->paInstances->removeElement($paInstance)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($paInstance->getSubscriber() === $this) {
                $paInstance->setSubscriber(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    }

This is the PaInstances entity
class PaInstances
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
        /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Subscribers::class, inversedBy="paInstances")
     */
    private $subscriber;
    
     public function getSubscriber(): ?Subscribers
    {
        return $this->subscriber;
    }

    public function setSubscriber(?Subscribers $subscriber): self
    {
        $this->subscriber = $subscriber;

        return $this;
    }
    }
```

And in `show_subscriber.html.twig` i wanna do something like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info " >Create PA </button>
```

that will open a modal window  where i can create the PaInstance for that specific subscriber.

Comment: Read https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: I did but i was not able to understand it properly

Comment: There is a docs page for how to add new elements to a collection (you basically have to map your things like this: Subscribers ~ Task, PaInstance ~ Tag):  https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html Adding a new item (like you want to do with the button) is described in this section: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype If you run into troubles/things don't work, please let us know which step and what exactly is not working (and how it differs).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Usually, you should not do such work in Twig, as this is a templating language

Comment: oh my god.. i am so dumb :D in the form i wrote entity_type .. not entry_type :) Thank you all